# Updating char* function C++

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to do some simple updating of a string in a function, I got the following sample to work:

```
void change(char* buffer) {
  buffer[0] = 'b';
}

void main() {
  char buffer[20] = "abc   def   ghi   j\0";
  printf("before: .%s., %p\n", buffer, buffer);
  change(buffer);
  printf("after:  .%s.\n", buffer);
}
```

But if I use char* for buffer instead of char[], I get an error in the function.  So the following example doesn't work:

```
void compact(char* buffer) {
  buffer[0] = 'b';
}

void main() {
  char* buffer="abc   def ghi\0";
  printf("before: .%s., %p\n", buffer, buffer);
  change(buffer);
  printf("after:  .%s.\n", buffer);
}
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

Don

Comment: BTW, '\0' is implied at the end of a "" string in C & C++, so you're actually double-terminating it, which is unnecessary (though not harmful).

Comment: You might be amazed, but [your code isn't actually C++](http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `char*`, your variable points to a **string literal** and invokes undefined behaviour.

You can't modify a string literal. When you declare a pointer like this

```
char* buffer="abc   def ghi\0";
```

`buffer` will point to read-only memory (probably, implementation defined). Regardless, you can't change its contents. This syntax was kept for compatibility with C, but, IMO, this shouldn't compile. Whenever you see something like that (`char*` pointing to a C-string), immediately translate it, inside your head, to

```
const char* buffer="abc   def ghi\0";
```

Put on your C++ glasses. If you don't have them, get a pair (you'll see all sorts of stuff, like this, returning locals by reference, forgetting to return, and many more).

The other case:

```
char buffer[] = "abc   def ghi\0";
```

is fine because you actually create an array of the required size and populate it with that content. This is no longer a pointer to a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a *literal*, you can only change a variable. You're trying to do the equivalent of this:

```
void increment(int &f) { ++f; }

increment(2);
```

Clearly that makes no sense. To modify a value, it must be stored somewhere in memory your code allocated. You can't modify a constant without copying it first.

Comment: In early versions of FORTRAN you could do that. Literal values were stored in read/write memory.

Comment: There's a stray `&` in the call to `increment()`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Nice catch. Fixed. I used to play with VAX Fortran, and yeah, you could change the value of `2` this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* buffer="abc   def ghi\0";
```

It's a contant string, you can't modify it.

Most compiler will give you a warning because you use ***char**** ( not ***const char**** )point to the const string.